# Call JavaScript On VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net

How can I call:

```
$("#buttonSKU").on('click', function() {
$("#floatDiv").fadeIn();   
});
```

on my VB.NET code under if:

```
@Code

Dim db = Database.Open("Users")
Dim SS_ID = Request.QueryString("SS_ID")
Dim initial_QRY
Dim yesInsert_QRY
Dim yesSelect_QRT

Dim ctrRecord

If SS_ID <> "" then

    initial_QRY = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_rsSKUSetup WHERE SKUSetup_ItemID='" & SS_ID & "'"

    ctrRecord = db.Query(initial_QRY).Count

        If ctrRecord = 0 Then

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\ushuam00\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite5\_Files\skuSetupGenericData.xlsm")
            System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "floatDiv", True)
        Else If ctrRecord > O Then

        Else 

End Code
```

Comment: For starters, you have an SQL injection problem that you should fix...

Comment: Please, explain further. For now, I can say that you call  `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and the script is executed, but after all code be run, in some point where the HTML is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If you're using asp.net webforms, use a asp-server button and a click event on the button. And write your code inside the button event handler.

If you really want to make the code to execute in js, you should make a ajax-request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
You could make a ajax-call GET to a page (url):

```
var ssid = 123; 
$.get("mypage.aspx", { SS_ID : ssid  } function( data ) {
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    Sub GreetingBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                          ByVal e As EventArgs)

        ' When the button is clicked,
        ' change the button text, and disable it.

        Dim clickedButton As Button = sender
        clickedButton.Text = "...button clicked..."
        clickedButton.Enabled = False

        ' Display the greeting label text.
        GreetingLabel.Visible = True
    End Sub

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Button Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <h3>Simple Button Example</h3>

      <asp:Button id="Button1"
           Text="Click here for greeting..."
           OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
      <br />
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="GreetingLabel" runat="server" 
                 Visible="false" Text="Hello World!" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html
```

>

Comment: I haven't touch on AJAX yet. Well, better start now :)